# back and forward buttons in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Firefox had problems with one specific site: clicking on any link showed the animated circle, indicating that the page was being fetched. But further nothing happened, and I couldn't even close the tab! Therefore I decided to reset Firefox, realizing that I might have to redo a lot of configuration.
One of the things I had before were a left button and a right button on my toolbar, to go to the previous and next site, resp. But when I opened the "customize" window the buttons weren't there. Have they been removed from version 33, or are they hidden somewhere?

Comment: Just a guess, are they context sensitive? If there is nowhere to back / forward to / from then they are hidden, they aren't specific buttons you can add or remove and appear or disappear from beside the navigation bar as needed?

Comment: @Richard - When back or forward didn't apply the buttons were grayed out, but still there. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have version 33 and they are there. When you say reset, is:

a. unistall and install firefox

b. erase the firefox profile

Did you try:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/701756 -> And this:

- If you see the item in the Customize window then drag it back from the Customize window to the Navigation toolbar.
- If you do not see that item then click the  Restore Default Set  button in the View > Toolbars > Customize window.

In View > Toolbars > Customize  window, do you have a screen like this?
http://screencast.com/t/uMesCvvT

Comment: By reset I mean "reset to default state" (Help | Troubleshooting information | reset). I've updated to version 33 now, and they're still not there.

Comment: Yes, I see the screen you posted on screencast. (But this also doesn't show the buttons, and neither are they on the toolbar.)

Comment: Do you still have important configurations there? I think you could try a Restore Defaults in the screencast screen